# Does notifyItemChanged() force a call to onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I call `notifyItemChanged()` on my `RecyclerView`, the corresponding `Views` (in this case, buttons) do not get updated as expected. The reason I am calling them is that data has changed which would cause their background color to change. Does this mean that `notifyItemChanged(`) doesn't force a call to `onBindViewHolder()`?

I tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and that DOES cause the views to reload as I want, so I know my implementation is correct. (Note I don't want to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, as that is inefficient, I only used it as a sanity test).

Answer (score 2):

To Refresh  your listview Register a new observer to listen for data changes.
using [registerAdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#registerAdapterDataObserver(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver))

The adapter may publish a variety of events describing specific changes. Not all adapters may support all change types and some may fall back to a generic "something changed" event if more specific data is not available.

Components registering observers with an adapter are responsible for unregistering those observers when finished.

Comment: It's unclear how to use this, namely because this is an observer for the entire adapter yet has no function that specifies a single position (onChange() specifies none and onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount) specifies a range)